# Python If None then check not None from other variables

Tags: python, if-statement

Im trying to get some value from user input in Python using get opts.

Im passing Cid, Sid, starttime, endtime

My program needs only Cid and Sid. Due to some reasons if Sid is not available, then we have an API call to get the value based on starttime or endtime.

So if the Sid has None then check who is not none starttime or endtime. Then use that value to get the Sid from an API call.

I have completed the code to check Cid and Sid, but im stuck in writing logic for

```
If Sid is none
then check starttime and endtime
Either one should have value.
then sid=API_CALL with starttime (or) endtime
```

#### My Code:

```
import getopt
from sys import exit, argv

def main(input_args):
    sid = None
    cid = None
    starttime = None
    endtime = None

    try:
        optlist,  remaining = getopt.getopt(input_args[1:], "", ['sid=','cid=','starttime=','endtime='])
        print(optlist)
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        exit()


    for arg,  value in optlist:
        if arg == "--cid":
            cid = value
        elif arg == "--sid":
            sid = value
        elif arg == "--starttime":
            starttime = value
        elif arg == "--endtime":
            endtime = value
        else:
            print "Unknown argument %s" % arg
    if (snapshotid is None):

        ### My logic should go there ###
        ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ####


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will directly translate your pseudocode:

```
if (snapshotid is None):

    ### My logic should go there ###
    ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ####

    if (starttime is None) and (endtime is None): raise Exception("Hmm")
    elif (starttime is not None) and (endtime is not None): raise Exception("Hmm2")
    elif starttime is None: sid=API_CALL(endtime)
    else: sid=API_CALL(starttime)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
if snapshotid is None:
    api_call(starttime or endtime)
```

In that case, if `snapshotid` is None, the api call will be made with `starttime` unless it's not logically false (None, False, empty string, etc..) or `endtime` (if `starttime` is logically false) or `None` if both `starttime` and `endtime` are logically false.